# Can I merge an off-topic and deleted self-answered question with an on-topic answer of the same content?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, merged-questions

I have a bunch of very similar self-answered questions in my recent deletions. At first, they were off-topic since I had asked for a software recommendation.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63298941/on-64bit-how-can-i-use-vscode-java-extension-on-java-below-version-11-after-the
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63298825/how-can-i-use-vscode-java-on-windows-32bit-after-the-new-requirement-of-java-11
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436626/how-can-i-use-vscode-java-on-windows-32bit-after-the-new-requirement-of-java-11

The three Q/As on the same topic are just a rest of having two questions for 32 bit and 64 bit at first, merging that, getting that deleted, posting a new one and then getting asked to put it on Super User. Result: https://superuser.com/questions/1575987/how-to-use-vscode-java-v0-65-0-with-older-java-jdk11-64bit-or-with-any-compat

But it is not about that Super User question.

**The question**

I would like to know if I can merge the three Q/As above with one answer at *[VSCode showing "Java 11 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043585/vscode-showing-java-11-or-more-recent-is-required-to-run-please-download-and-i/63287737)* when all contributions are quite similar or at least evolving over time to that answer.

Comment: Not sure what exactly preventing you to do so?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I will answer my own question with the most likely ***"no"***.

This meta question is about trying to merge [***Q/As*** that have almost the same content as a given ***answer***] --> into that ***answer***. Which is impossible, as it mixes up questions and answers.

If a moderator knows another possibility, please comment.

Answer (score 8):

Moderators merge questions because they are basically identical but all have worthy answers. After the merge we have a single question with all the good answers together in one place. That has value to everyone as we can all read all of those answers easily without hunting separately for them.

There seems little value in moderators merging your deleted questions because we won't be doing that, and we won't even achieve the thing you want which is to get you out of your question ban. According to [animuson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400226/merge-three-deleted-questions-with-three-answers-all-q-as-very-similar-into-on#comment789009_400226)

> Merging questions doesn't work that way. Merging would move the answers and comments and lock the merged question, but it still remains as a question that is closed and deleted. It doesn't disappear completely.

Comment: Then I could at least try to merge all three questions and answers into one deleted Q/A. Which is already achieved at https://superuser.com/questions/1575987/how-to-use-vscode-java-v0-65-0-with-older-java-jdk11-64bit-or-with-any-compat, thus there is no extra work to be done anymore. That would save me two out of three deletions, without having to merge a question with an answer anymore.

Comment: The question is, what value would that have to anyone except yourself?

Comment: No value to anyone else, as you state it. And some work for the moderator. But it is also an exceptional thing and I am still new to Stack Overflow, it could be a good sign to other contributers if banned users get at least little help by the mods in such cases.

Comment: @Lorenz There's a lot of question-banned users and only a handful of moderators. If that becomes a common thing it's going to overwhelm them and prevent them from doing their actual job.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery that is understood. I just think it is an exceptional case. Yet, this is off-topic to this question here. I should rather ask a new one.

Comment: Done at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400226/merge-three-deleted-questions-with-three-answers-all-q-as-very-similar-into-on, without closing this question here though, since your answer does not convince me completely. What if I just undeleted the three questions and asked for a merge? Could that just be refused? I could just try it, couldn't I?

Comment: After the edit of this answer the question remains whether the ban algorithm changes its points when a question was merged - even when the questions remain as they are. And probably no one here will be able to say this, because it is officially not known on purpose what the algorithm calculates exactly. That is why I cannot accept the answer even after the good edit that first seems so promising.

Comment: @SecurityHound I just see that this is out of scope at this meta question here, your advice appreciated. This is about trying to merge Q/As that have merely the same content as a given answer *into* that answer. Which is probably impossible, as it mixes up questions and answers. I will still answer your comment at https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400226/merge-three-deleted-questions-with-one-answer-each-and-all-q-as-very-similar.