# Merge three deleted questions (with one answer each, and all Q/As very similar) into one deleted Q/A?

Tags: support, specific-question, deleted-questions, deleted-answers, merged-questions

This is a spin-off from [Can I merge an off-topic and deleted self-answered question with an on-topic answer of the same content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/400224/can-i-merge-an-off-topic-and-deleted-self-answered-question-with-an-on-topic-ans).

I have a bunch of very similar self-answered questions in my recent deletions. At first, they where off-topic since I had asked for a software recommendation.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63298941/on-64bit-how-can-i-use-vscode-java-extension-on-java-below-version-11-after-the
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63298825/how-can-i-use-vscode-java-on-windows-32bit-after-the-new-requirement-of-java-11
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436626/how-can-i-use-vscode-java-on-windows-32bit-after-the-new-requirement-of-java-11

The three Q/As on the same topic are just a rest of having two questions for 32bit and 64bit at first, merging that, getting that deleted, posting a new one and then getting asked to put it on Super User, result: https://superuser.com/questions/1575987/how-to-use-vscode-java-v0-65-0-with-older-java-jdk11-64bit-or-with-any-compat

But it is not about that Super User question.

**The question**

I would like to know if I can merge the three Q/As above to one Q/A. The Q/A is already prepared, it could be taken from [VSCode showing "Java 11 or more recent is required to run. Please download and install a recent JDK"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63043585/vscode-showing-java-11-or-more-recent-is-required-to-run-please-download-and-i/63287737).

I know that this is extra work for the few mods at SO. This should be a rather exceptional case though.

Comment: If the final question is still going to be deleted, what exactly would be the point of expending effort merging questions?

Comment: @animuson I think that the algorithm for the question ban also counts the number of deleted and downvoted questions, no one knows how it works exactly. If I have just one strongly downvoted deleted question, it might cancel the ban.

Comment: Merging questions doesn't work that way. Merging would move the answers and comments and lock the merged question, but it still remains as a question that is closed and deleted. It doesn't disappear completely.

Comment: @Lorenz What makes this an exceptional case? Why should the moderators put in that work for you specifically, other than just you not wanting to be question banned?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery It is exceptional because I do not expect a lot of similar issues where you have: three deleted SO Q/As (-1,-3,-5) that exist almost in the same way in one other Q/A on Super User (and upvoted), with the summary of the three questions' answers being upvoted at an answer of an on-topic question on SO, with the high similarity of all three SO Q/As. And all of this causing at least 50 % of the ban.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219774/discussion-on-question-by-lorenz-merge-three-deleted-questions-with-one-answer).

Answer (score -8, accepted):

EDIT of the whole answer.

After the helpful comments, I try to sum it up to an answer myself.

The comment of @animuson:

> Merging would move the answers and comments and lock the merged
> question, but it still remains as a question that is closed and
> deleted. It doesn't disappear completely.

The comment of @SecurityHound:

> Deleted or merged questions always exist. In the case of a merged
> question a placeholder question exists. Nobody can view It but it
> still exists. So a merger would count against your ability to ask new
> questions. You would gain no reputation from the existing question
> that received upvotes; You would simply have three deleted questions.

This would mean that the work on merging three ***Q/As*** would keep any ***Q*** in its existence, even if the ***As*** and ***comments*** would be taken to just one placeholder ***Q***. That means that three questions would remain (and the placeholder ***Q*** does not count as a normal question).

Yet. There is a chance that the algorithm considers the merging as positive, though it is unclear as no one knows the exact algorithm.

After all, it seems to be just up to me to try the merger or not, as it seems to be formally possible, but might have no effect on the points of the algorithm. For now, I avoid the extra work on both sides. It is unlikely that I will find a moderator who is willing to undelete the questions only for a merger that again would be deleted (or migrated to Super User, which would only be possible if I also delete the already existing ***Q/A*** there at first), and even if that worked out well, it is too vague whether it would help at all, since the three deleted questions would still remain on SO.

Comment: **I also never said a fourth question would be created.**

Comment: OK, I edited that by "and the placeholder Q does not count as a normal question".